# Curiously Recurring Template Pattern, Multiple Layers of Inheritance

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, crtp

Building off of the work done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3453326/is-there-an-alternative-to-the-curiously-recurring-template-pattern), I've defined a generic, abstract base class for enumerations, like so:

```
public abstract class Enumeration<T> : IEquatable<T> where T : Enumeration<T>
{
    private static IEnumerable<T> enumerateAllValues()
    {
        // Obviously use some caching here
        var fields = typeof(T).GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);
        return fields.Select(f => f.GetValue(null)).OfType<T>();
    }

    internal static IEnumerable<T> AllValues {get { return enumerateAllValues();}}

    protected Enumeration(int value, string displayName)
    {
        if (!typeof(T).IsSealed)
            throw new NotSupportedException($"Value objects must be sealed, {typeof(T).Name} is not.");
        this.Value = value;
        this.DisplayName = displayName;
    }

    protected int Value { get; }

    protected string DisplayName { get; }

    public override string ToString() { return DisplayName; }       
    // IEquatable implementation based solely on this.Value
}
```

And a static, non-generic helper class to parse and list values of an enum:

```
public static class Enumeration 
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> GetAllValues<T>() where T : Enumeration<T>
        {
            return Enumeration<T>.AllValues;
        }
    // Other helper methods, e.g. T Parse(int), bool TryParse(int, out T), etc.
}
```

Now, I derive from this with another abstract class to represent a certain class of enumerations that have something in common:

```
public abstract class AnimalTrait<T> : Enumeration<AnimalTrait<T>>
{
    protected AnimalTrait(int value, string displayName) : base(value, displayName) { ; }
}
```

So far so good. As an example the concrete class deriving from this might be DogTrait, or FishTrait, etc. Knowing that all animal traits can be paired with a value, and supposing that the value of an animal trait is always a string, I then define another abstract class like so:

```
public struct AnimalTraitValuePair<TAnimalTrait> where TAnimalTrait : AnimalTrait<TAnimalTrait>
{

    public TAnimalTrait AnimalTrait { get; }

    public string Value { get; } // Analogy breaks down here, but lets assume we know that the values of animal traits are always strings.

    public AnimalTraitValuePair(TAnimalTrait animalTrait, string value)
    {
        this.AnimalTrait = animalTrait;
        this.Value = value;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"[{AnimalTrait}, {Value}]";
    }
}
```

Similar to deriving from `KeyValuePair<TAnimalTrait, string> where TAnimalTrait : AnimalTrait<TAnimalTrait>`, which I would do if it wasn't a struct.

Now when I go to define the Animal class that holds the name of the animal and it's list of AnimalTrait's with their associated values, i.e. a list of `AnimalTraitValuePair<TAnimal>`, I run into a problem:

```
public abstract class Animal<TAnimal, TAnimalTrait> :
    where TAnimal : Animal<TAnimal, TAnimalTrait>
    where TAnimalTrait : AnimalTrait<TAnimalTrait>
{
    private readonly IList<AnimalTraitValuePair<TAnimalTrait>> animalTraitValuePairList;

    // All animals have a name
    public string Name {get;}

    protected Animal(string name, IEnumerable<AnimalTraitValuePair<TAnimalTrait>> animalTraitValuePairs)
    {
        animalTraitValuePairList = animalTraitValuePairs.ToList();
        this.Name = name;
    }

    public string this[TAnimalTrait animalTrait]
    {
        get
        {
            return animalTraitValuePairList.First(atvp => atvp.AnimalTrait == animalTrait).Value;
        }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        // !!!! BREAKS HERE !!!!
        foreach (var animalTrait in Enumeration.GetAllValues<AnimalTrait<TAnimalTrait>>()) // This works...
        //foreach (var animalTrait in Enumeration.GetAllValues<TAnimalTrait>()) // ...but this doesn't
        {
            sb.AppendLine($"{this.Name}'s traits:");
            sb.AppendLine($"[{animalTrait}, {animalTrait.Value}]");
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

I get this compiler error:

> `The type 'TAnimalTrait' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'Enumeration.GetAllValues<T>()'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'TAnimalTrait' to 'Maxim.Common.Enums.Enumeration<TAnimalTrait>'`

Why can't I use TAnimalTrait directly?  Is not TAnimalTrait restricted to be a class of `AnimalTrait<TAnimalTrait>`, which we know is an Enumeration and therefore can be upcasted two levels to the base `Enumeration<T>`? Is the one that compiles "correct" and give me the behavior I want?

Comment: Your code has a number of typos in it. Please take some time to clean up your code so that it will compile enough to produce the behavior you're describing.

Comment: Sorry, I fixed one typo. I'll get the others as soon as I can and make sure it compiles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were a number of problems with your code, and I lost track of all the things I had to change, but here's a working snippet:

```
void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine(Dog.Fido.ToString());
}

public abstract class Enumeration<T> where T : Enumeration<T>
{
    private static IEnumerable<T> enumerateAllValues()
    {
        // Obviously use some caching here
        var fields = typeof(T).GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);
        return fields.Select(f => f.GetValue(null)).OfType<T>();
    }

    internal static IEnumerable<T> AllValues { get { return enumerateAllValues();}}

    protected Enumeration(int value, string displayName)
    {
        if (!typeof(T).IsSealed)
            throw new NotSupportedException($"Value objects must be sealed, {typeof(T).Name} is not.");
        this.Value = value;
        this.DisplayName = displayName;
    }

    protected int Value { get; }

    protected string DisplayName { get; }

    public override string ToString() { return DisplayName; }       
        // IEquatable implementation based solely on this.Value
}

public static class Enumeration
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> GetAllValues<T>() where T : Enumeration<T>
    {
        return Enumeration<T>.AllValues;
    }
    // Other helper methods, e.g. T Parse(int), bool TryParse(int, out T), etc.
}

public abstract class AnimalTrait<T> : Enumeration<T>
    where T : AnimalTrait<T>
{
    protected AnimalTrait(int value, string displayName) : base(value, displayName) {; }
}

public struct AnimalTraitValuePair<TAnimalTrait> where TAnimalTrait : AnimalTrait<TAnimalTrait>
{

    public TAnimalTrait AnimalTrait { get; }

    public string Value { get; } // Analogy breaks down here, but lets assume we know that the values of animal traits are always strings.

    public AnimalTraitValuePair(TAnimalTrait animalTrait, string value)
    {
        this.AnimalTrait = animalTrait;
        this.Value = value;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"[{AnimalTrait}, {Value}]";
}
}

public abstract class Animal<TAnimal, TAnimalTrait> : Enumeration<TAnimal>
    where TAnimal : Animal<TAnimal, TAnimalTrait>
    where TAnimalTrait : AnimalTrait<TAnimalTrait>
{
    private readonly IList<AnimalTraitValuePair<TAnimalTrait>> animalTraitValuePairList;

    // All animals have a name
    public string Name { get; }

    protected Animal(int i, string name, IEnumerable<AnimalTraitValuePair<TAnimalTrait>> animalTraitValuePairs)
        : base(i, name)
    {
        animalTraitValuePairList = animalTraitValuePairs.ToList();
        this.Name = name;
    }

    public string this[TAnimalTrait animalTrait]
    {
        get
        {
            return animalTraitValuePairList.First(atvp => atvp.AnimalTrait == animalTrait).Value;
        }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.AppendLine($"{this.Name}'s traits:");
        foreach (var animalTrait in Enumeration.GetAllValues<TAnimalTrait>())
        {
            sb.AppendLine($"[{animalTrait}, {this[animalTrait]}]");
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}

public sealed class DogTrait : AnimalTrait<DogTrait>
{
    public DogTrait(int i, string name) 
        : base(i, name)
    { }
    public static DogTrait Color = new DogTrait(1, "Color");
    public static DogTrait Size = new DogTrait(2, "Size");
}

public sealed class Dog : Animal<Dog, DogTrait>
{
    public Dog(int i, string name, IEnumerable<AnimalTraitValuePair<DogTrait>> animalTraitValuePairs)
        : base(i, name, animalTraitValuePairs)
    {
    }
    public static Dog Fido = new Dog(1, "Fido", new[] {
        new AnimalTraitValuePair<DogTrait>(DogTrait.Color, "Black"),
        new AnimalTraitValuePair<DogTrait>(DogTrait.Size, "Medium"),
    });
}
```

Output:

> Fido's traits:
>   [Color, Black]
>   [Size, Medium]

Comment: Thanks!! The trick, I believe, was to change the signature of the abstract enumeration subclass from `abstract class AnimalTrait<T> : Enumeration<AnimalTrait<T>>` to `abstract class AnimalTrait<T> : Enumeration<T> where T : AnimalTrait<T>`. Although I'm not sure why this would make a difference, it does. (I'll be sure to put up cleaner code next time, I was copying/pasting/renaming from a much larger example)

Comment: I've finished cleaning up the original question. Thanks for also fixing some of the code blocks.

Comment: Also in this case Animal should not derive from Enumeration because there is not a predefined list of animals.

Answer (score 0):

You have a constraint on AnimalTraitValuePair

```
public struct AnimalTraitValuePair<TAnimalTrait> 
   where TAnimalTrait : AnimalTrait<TAnimalTrait>
```

When you use it you are passing in a TAnimal with Animal constraint

```
public abstract class Animal<TAnimal, TAnimalTrait> 
    : IEnumerable<AnimalTraitValuePair<TAnimal>>
    where TAnimal : Animal<TAnimal, TAnimalTrait>
    where TAnimalTrait : AnimalTrait<TAnimalTrait>
```

If you change it to the following:

```
public abstract class Animal<TAnimal, TAnimalTrait> 
:  IEnumerable<AnimalTraitValuePair<TAnimalTrait>>
    where TAnimal : Animal<TAnimal, TAnimalTrait>
    where TAnimalTrait : AnimalTrait<TAnimalTrait>
```

You will get a error stating that

```
Enumeration<AnimalTrait<TAnimalTrait>>.Value is inaccessable due to its protection level.
```

This occurs because your Animal class doesn't derive from Enumeration<AnimalTraitValuePair<TAnimalTrait>>

Honestly, being that IList<T> is a generic implementation of IEnumerable<T>, if you want a simple implementation that accomplishes the same goal, I'd just do the following:

```
public class Animal
{
   private IList<AnimalTrait> _traits;
   public Animal(IList<AnimalTrait> traits)
   {
       _traits = traits;
   }
   public IEnumerable<AnimalTrait> Traits{get{return _traits;}}
}

public class AnimalTrait
{
   public int Value{get;set;}
   public string DisplayName{get;set;}
}
```